# Python3 threading about lock.acquire

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, locking

When I test

```
import threading

def job1():
    global A
    a = lock.acquire()
    print(a)
    for i in range(10):
        A+=1
        print('job1',A)
    lock.release()

def job2():
    global A
    for i in range(10):
        A+=10
        print('job2',A)

if __name__== '__main__':
    lock=threading.Lock()
    A=0
    t1=threading.Thread(target=job1)
    t2=threading.Thread(target=job2)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

most of the time, the result was (condition 1):

```
True
job1 1
job1 2
job1 3
job1 4
job1 5
job1 6
job1 7
job1 8
job1 9
job1 10
job2 20
job2 30
job2 40
job2 50
job2 60
job2 70
job2 80
job2 90
job2 100
job2 110
```

But One of the result was (condition 2)

```
True
job1 1
job1 2
job1 3
job1 4
job1 5
job1 6
job1 7
job2 17
job2 27
job2 37
job2 47
job2 57
job2 67
job2 77
job2 87
job2 97
job2 107
job1 108
job1 109
job1 110
```

I should have locked the thread in `job1`, why did result 2 come out?

I found the result will always be condition 1 if I add another `lock.acquire` and `lock.release` statement in `job2`, but Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a thread-safe counter inside `Lock` instance, and `lock.acquire` means if counter bigger than 0, then pass, else block. `lock.release` means `counter = counter + 1`.

So to sync two threads, you need to use lock inside both threads. If `job1` doesn't `lock.release`, counter is 0 and the `lock.acquire` inside `job2` will block until `job1` call `lock.release`.

That is how lock works basically.

## Update

There isn't any lock inside `job2` unless you **do use a lock inside it**. I know what you want, you want to block `job2` until `job1` call `lock.release`. But you need to explicitly tell `job2` to block by calling `lock.acquire`. Or how could `job2` know itself should be blocked?

Going further, suppose you have two different lock instances `a, b` and two pairs of threads `jobA1, jobA2, jobB1, jobB2`. You can use `a` to synchronize `jobA1` and `jobA2` and use `b` to synchronize `jobB1` and `jobB2`. But you need explicitly tell every thread which lock they should use.

Comment: Under this condition, I didn't use lock.acquire in job2 and I used release in job1, so why could job2 break the lock sometimes?